# How to add a custom variable that can be accessed on bootstrap's menu--account.html.twig?

Tags: theming, 8, hooks

I have a custom theme (subtheme of drupal bootstrap theme).  We are overriding `menu--account.html.twig`.  So I copied `menu--account.html.twig` from the bootstrap theme template folder into my theme's template folder, and I verified this template is being used because static text changes I added show up on screen.

Now I'm trying to add a variable that the `menu--account.html.twig` template can read.

How do I do that?  My variable's name is 'nickname'.  I tried this:

```
 function mymodule_preprocess_menu__account(&$variables)
 {     
     $variables['nickname'] = 'Jeff';     
 }
```

The variable is added to the array, and I can see it if I use dpm, but when I reference {{nickname}} in the template it's always null.

I also read I had to define the variable like this:

```
 function candidate_poral_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry)
 {
   $theme_registry['menu__account']['variables']['nickname'] = 'default';
 }
```

But that also doesn't work.

Any assistance would be welcome.

Comment: Have to ask, but is your theme registry alter hook spelled correctly? I noticed it says poral instead of portal. Can you verify the code is being hit on cache clear?

Comment: Well, you're right about the misspelling, but fixing it didn't have any effect other than allowing me to confirm (by dumpign $theme_registry via dsm) that the registry alter hook is being called on a cache clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this for a theme on past projects. Be sure to pass it in through the `content` item:

**Example**

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

function mytheme_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) { 
  $theme_registry['menu__account']['variables']['nickname'] = 'default'; 
}

function mytheme_preprocess_menu__account(&$variables) {
  // code...

  $variables['content']['#nickname'] = [
    .. renderable properties
  ];

  // or also...

  $variables['content']['#nickname'] = Markup::create('Jeff');
}
```

Then, in the twig template:

`{{ custom_var }}`