# Adding a variable to a menu twig template

Tags: 8, theming, bootstrap-theme

Im trying to use bootstrap for an accordion menu. My issue is that I need unique ID's for each accordion item. I found some similar topics here: [Add Unique ID to Menu Item](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254318/add-unique-id-to-menu-item) and here: [How to add a custom variable that can be accessed on bootstrap's menu--account.html.twig?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248818/how-to-add-a-custom-variable-that-can-be-accessed-on-bootstraps-menu-account-h)

Id like to know how I can get a unique ID for each item. Preferably an ID I can store within a variable which I can then pass to the data target attribute. As you can see in my code below, I'm trying to achieve something like that. The issue is that I cannot use the variable in a twig template that I declared within the preprocess function. Help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code in my .theme file:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_menu__main(array &$variables) {
    $id = 0;
    foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
      $variables['items'][$key]['accordionNav']=[];
      $key_hash = hash('crc32b', $key);
      $variables['items'][$key]['accordionNav'] = $key_hash ;
}
}
```

Here is my twig file menu--main.html.twig:

```
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}

    {% if menu_level == 0 %}

      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('nav navbar-nav').setAttribute('id', 'accordion') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul class="sub-menu card-body">

    {% endif %}

    {% for item in items %}

      {%
        set classes = [
          menu_level ? 'sub-item' : 'nav-item',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
          item.below ? 'card',
        ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {%
          set link_classes = [
            not menu_level ? 'nav-link',
            item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
            item.url.getOption('attributes').class ? item.url.getOption('attributes').class | join(' '),
            'nav-link-' ~ item.url.toString() | clean_class,
          ]
        %}
        {% if item.below %}
        {% if item.in_active_trail %}
        <div class="card-header" id="heading{{ip}}">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{accordionNav}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{ip}}">

          {{ item.title }}
         </button>
         </div>

         <div id="collapse{{ip}}" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading{{ip}}" data-parent="#accordion">
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
          {% else %}
          <div class="card-header" id="heading{{ip}}">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{accordionNav}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{ip}}">

          {{ item.title }}
         </button>
         </div>

         <div id="collapse{{ip}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading{{ip}}" data-parent="#accordion">
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
         {% endif %}

        </div>
        {% else %}
          {{ link(item.title, item.url, {'class': link_classes}) }}

        {% endif %}

      </li>

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: Id like to know how I can get a unique ID for each item. Preferably an ID I can store within a variable which I can then pass to the data target attribute. As you can see in my code below, I'm trying to achieve something like that. The issue is that I cannot use the variable in a twig template that I declared within the preprocess function.

Comment: What's the name of your twig file?

Comment: name of my twig file is: menu--main.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

You could use directly the derivative id (which will be unique) of the menu item in twig, with:

```
item.original_link.getDerivativeId()
```

otherwise you need to add a custom unique id in preprocess function to each item, like:

```
function yourtheme_menu_link_alter(&$item) {
  if($item['menu_name'] == 'custom-menu')
  {
    $item['uuid'] = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::getUniqueId($item['menu_name']);
  }
}
```

which you then access in twig with:

```
item.uuid
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on this answer please?

Comment: There you go ;)

Comment: thanks for the expalnation. Im having trouble setting the variable value. Here is my code to set the variable: {% set ids = ['nav-link-' ~ item.original_link.getDerivativeId() | clean_class] %}  not sure if im doing this right.